# Access the word in the file with SSH command

Tags: regex, ssh, grep

I have a conf file and I use GREP to access the data in this file but not a very useful method for me.

How can I just get the main word?

I using:

```
grep "HelloWorld" /etc/VDdatas.conf
```

Print:

```
export: HelloWorld
```

I want: *(without "export: ")*

```
HelloWorld
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the -o or --only-matching option, if you're using gnu grep.  It shows only the parts of each line that match..

```
grep -o "HelloWorld" /etc/VDdatas.conf
```

Comment: Is it possible to search in reverse? For example; can I get the word "HelloWorld" if I call "export" ?